# How do I apply a `map` operation on the promised values of an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm familiar with doing an map operation like this on arrays

```
[1,2,3].map(x=>x = x + 1);
```

What I have is a map of promises e.g.

```
const objOfPromises = {
  'a': Promise.resolve(1),
  'b': Promise.resolve(2),
  'c': Promise.resolve(3),
}
```

Is there a way of doing something like

```
const objOfResolvedPromises = await objOfPromises.map(promise => await promise)
```

Comment: You cannot use `.map` on objects but you can do similar transinformation using `Object.entries(obj).map()`. With that said, what exactly do you expect out of this? Is the result supposed to be `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map to an array of Promises that resolves to an entry array (an array with 2 elements, a key and a value), and use `Promise.all` and then `Object.fromEntries` to turn it back into an object.

```js
const objOfPromises = {
  'a': Promise.resolve(1),
  'b': Promise.resolve(2),
  'c': Promise.resolve(3),
};
Promise.all(
  Object.entries(objOfPromises).map(
    ([key, prom]) => prom.then(resolveVal => [key, resolveVal])
  )
)
  .then((resolvedEntries) => {
    const objOfResolvedPromises = Object.fromEntries(resolvedEntries);
    console.log(objOfResolvedPromises);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.values(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) in conjunction with [`Promise.all(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like this.

```js
const objOfPromises = {
  'a': Promise.resolve(1),
  'b': Promise.resolve(2),
  'c': Promise.resolve(3),
}

const arrayOfAllPromises = Object.values(objOfPromises);
const oneBigPromise = Promise.all(arrayOfAllPromises);

// OR

const arrayOfReturnValuesOfAllPromises = await Promise.all(arrayOfAllPromises);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also utilize the [async iterators](https://2ality.com/2016/10/asynchronous-iteration.html) abstraction here to create an `AsyncMappableObject` class.

```js
class AsyncMappableObject{
  constructor(o){
    Object.assign(this,o);
  }

  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator](){
    for (let k in this){
      yield this[k];
    }
  }
  
  map(f){
    let mapped = Object.create(this);
    for (let k in this){
      mapped[k] = this[k].then(f);
    }
    return mapped;
  }
}

var objOfPromises = { 'a': Promise.resolve(1)
                    , 'b': Promise.resolve(2)
                    , 'c': Promise.resolve(3)
                    };

var amo = new AsyncMappableObject(objOfPromises);

async function run(){ 
  for await(let v of amo.map(x => x*2)){
    console.log(v);
  }

  for await(let v of amo){
    console.log(v);
  }
}

run();
```